# $H^{\infty}$ is not separable

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

> Consider the Hardy space, $(H^{\infty},\|•\|{\tiny{\infty}})$ where, $$  \|f\|{\tiny{\infty}} = \sup\{f(z) : z\in\mathbb{D} \}<\infty,$$ 
>   for a $f\in H^{\infty}.$ Prove that $H^{\infty}$ is not separable.

**My attempt:**

I tried to find, $\phi^{i}$, $i\in I,$ functions, holomorphic, bounded over the unit disk, such that, $$B = \{\phi^{i} : i\in I\}$$ has uncountably many members and for every $i,j\in I$ with $i \neq j$, there exists a M>0 : $\|\phi^{i} - \phi^{j}\|{\tiny{\infty}}>M$.

But I cant find a spesific example that works. I tried for example $\phi^{t}(z) = e^{it}f(z)$ where $f\in H^{\infty}$. Its not easy, but there must be an elementary way to solve it, without using heavy theorems ( like interpolation theorems) or algebraic methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have a nice family of inner functions:

For $\zeta \in \partial \mathbb{D}$, let

$$f_{\zeta}(z) = \exp \biggl( \frac{z+\zeta}{z - \zeta}\biggr).$$

For $\zeta_1 \neq \zeta_2$, consider the radial limits of $f_{\zeta_k}$ at $\zeta_1$ to see $\lVert f_{\zeta_1} - f_{\zeta_2}\rVert_{\infty} \geqslant 1$.

Comment: No, we have $\operatorname{Re} \frac{z+\zeta}{z-\zeta} = \frac{\lvert z\rvert^2 - \lvert \zeta\rvert^2}{\lvert z-\zeta\rvert^2} < 0$ for $z\in \mathbb{D}$, and hence $\lvert f_{\zeta}(z)\rvert < 1$. The radial limit at $\zeta$ of $\frac{z+\zeta}{z-\zeta}$ is $-\infty$, $\frac{t\zeta + \zeta}{t\zeta - \zeta} = \frac{t+1}{t-1} \to -\infty$ as $t \to 1^-$.

Comment: I have no idea what that should mean. We're talking about the good old Hardy space $H^{\infty}$ of bounded holomorphic functions on the unit disk, aren't we?

Comment: The Möbius transformation $T\colon z \mapsto \frac{z+\zeta}{z-\zeta}$ maps the unit disk (conformally) to the left half-plane. Then the exponential function maps the left half-plane to the unit disk. So $f_{\zeta}\colon \mathbb{D}\to \mathbb{D}$. $T$ maps the diameter of the unit disk from $-\zeta$ to $\zeta$ onto the negative real axis, and thus $\lim\limits_{t\to 1^-} f_{\zeta}(t\cdot \zeta) = 0$. What are the radial limits at other points of the unit circle?

Comment: Yes, radial limit means you approach the boundary point along the radius. The point is **how** the exponent approaches $\infty$. Here the real part of the exponent is always negative, so $f_{\zeta}$ is bounded. And when you approach $\zeta$ along the radius, the exponent is real and tends to $-\infty$, so the radial limit of $f_{\zeta}$ at $\zeta$ is $0$.

Comment: $f_{\zeta}$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{\zeta\}$, so we can just plug other boundary points in. With $\psi = \frac{\phi - \theta}{2}$, we have $\frac{e^{i\phi}+e^{i\theta}}{e^{i\phi} - e^{i\theta}} = \frac{e^{i\psi}+e^{-i\psi}}{e^{i\psi} - e^{-i\psi}} = -i\cot \psi$, hence $f_{\zeta}(e^{i\phi}) = \exp \bigl(-i\cot \frac{\phi - \theta}{2}\bigr)$. The important thing is that $\lvert f_{\zeta}(e^{i\phi})\rvert = 1$ for $e^{i\phi} \neq \zeta$, and hence $\lVert f_{\zeta} - f_{e^{i\phi}}\rVert_{\infty} \geqslant 1$ for $e^{i\phi}\neq \zeta$.

Comment: Note that as $\phi \to \theta$, $f_{\zeta}(e^{i\phi})$ has no limit, the value wraps around the unit circle infinitely often. $f_{\zeta}$ has an essential singularity at $\zeta$ (we must take functions that aren't continuous on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$, since the disk algebra $A(\mathbb{D})\subsetneq H^{\infty}(\mathbb{D})$ is separable).

Comment: It's recommended not to do it, but thank you very much! Sorry for the silly comments.